# Problem with indirect communication between parent and child elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, dom-events

I have a problem with an indirect communication in react native.

I have a parent component, which is one component per class. And I have a child component that is a functional component.

Parent:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    search: '',
  };
 }

getInfoSearch(userSearch) {
 this.setState({
   search: userSearch
 })
}

render(){
  return(
   <SearchHeader placeholder={'Buscar procedimento'} getValueUserSearch={this.getInfoSearch}/>
  )
}
```

Child:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput} from 'react-native';

const SearchHeader = props => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

  const {placeholder, getValueUserSearch} = props;

  const handleSearch = (search) => {
    console.log(this);
    setSearch(search);
    getValueUserSearch(search);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput placeholder={placeholder || 'Buscar'} onChangeText={handleSearch}/>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SearchHeader;
```

But when I type text in the InputText, an error occurs. Stating that:

> "I cannot apply the setState function of undefined"

Do you know how I could solve this problem? Because I want to change the 'search' state in the parent element.

Comment: Use arrow function for `getInfoSearch`. Else do the binding at `constructor`

Comment: Value of `this` inside `getInfoSearch` method might not be what you expect it to be. Try to log `this` inside `getInfoSearch` and see what its value is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error might be because of `this.setState` line in  `getInfoSearch` function.

Try using `arrow function` or do the explicit binding in `constructor` as below

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.getInfoSearch = this.getInfoSearch.bind(this);
}
```

(Or)

```
getInfoSearch = (userSearch) => {
  this.setState({ search: userSearch });
}
```

Check [here](https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/when-to-use-arrow-functions) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not passing argument to the `handleSearch` function, it should be:

```
 onChangeText={(event) => handleSearch(event.target.value}
```